# How to put QGraphicsEffect on QScrollBar inside QScrollArea?

Tags: c++, qt

I try to set `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` on a `QScrollBar`. This code works:

```
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect * dse = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
dse->setBlurRadius(10);
dse->setColor(Qt::red);
dse->setOffset(0);
ui->verticalScrollBar->setGraphicsEffect(dse); // verticalScrollBar is `QScrollBar`.
```

However the following does not:

```
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect * dse = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
dse->setBlurRadius(10);
dse->setColor(Qt::red);
dse->setOffset(0);
ui->scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
ui->scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setGraphicsEffect(dse);
```

In the second example code I try to set effect on a slider inside `QScrollArea` but it does not apply to it. However, it can be applied to the whole `scrollArea` by `ui->scrollArea->setGraphicsEffect(dse)`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was caused by parent widget of `QScrollBar`. So, `QScrollArea` has item area and scroll bar area. Scroll bar area contains `QWidget`s and `QScrollBar`s actually placed on these `QWidgets`. So, to make this work I actually had to set effect for the parent widget:

```
for(auto *child : ui->scrollArea->findChildren<QScrollBar*>()) {
    if (child->orientation() == Qt::Vertical) {
        auto * dse = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
        dse->setBlurRadius(10);
        dse->setColor(Qt::red);
        dse->setXOffset(-3);
        dse->setYOffset(0);
        child->parentWidget()->setGraphicsEffect(dse);
        qDebug() << child->metaObject()->className(); // QScrollBar
        qDebug() << child->parentWidget()->metaObject()->className(); // QWidget
    }
}
```